# What is the Complexity Class of the "Function Variant" of the Integer Factorization Problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

I've been reading up a lot Prime Factorization and it's complexity, including a fair number of questions on this very site. However, I still feel there is a question still left unanswered.

So, basically, there is the "Decision Variant" of the *Integer Factorization Problem*, as it's officially known, as well as the "Function Variant". The "Decision Variant" simply asks whether a given integer n has a factor greater than 1.
The "Function Variant", on the other hand, concerns itself with actually finding the Prime Factors if there is more than 1 (it being equivalent to the "Decision Variant" if the answer to that is 'no').

When the question is asked *"In what complexity class does Integer Factorization lie"*, the answer given is usually along the lines of: *"The Decision Variant is both in NP and in Co-NP"*. That is great to know, but that question has been answered and does therefore not need answering again. I will therefore make my Question more specific.

**Question:**
*Is it known in what Complexity Class the "Function Variant" of the Integer Factorization Problem, aka the Prime Factorization Problem, lies? If so, what class would that be?*

Comment: Let F_n be the set of positive integers having precisely n prime facfors, counted with multiplicity.  For n=1, F_n has a polytime algorithm to decide if a number is in that set or not.  For n larger than 1, no such fast algorithm is currently known.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring is best thought of as defining a complexity class on its own. However, to put it in the context of commonly studied classes of NP search (function) problems: it is proved in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5220) paper of mine that integer factoring has a randomized polynomial-time reduction to [PPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPA_(complexity)) and  [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPP_(complexity)) (even a variant of PPP corresponding to the weak pigeonhole principle). Assuming the Riemann hypothesis for $L$-functions of quadratic Dirichlet characters, both reductions can be derandomized, putting factoring in PPA and in $\mathrm{FP^{PPP}}$. It is an open problem whether factoring is in [PPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPAD_(complexity)).